# Understanding Objective-C Overwrite Code

Tags: objective-c, xcode

**Disclaimer:** The program I wrote works. I just need help understanding it.

Today I just started learning XCode and Objective-C. I have tons of experience with Java and I must admit this is very different. I'm currently following a book that has us dealing with two scenes in our story board. The `Main View Controller Scene` and the `Flipside View Controller Scene`.

In the main scene I have one `label outlet` that says Hello World. It's name is label. In the flipside scene I have a `text outlet`. When the user flips from the flipside scene to the main scene the text in the text outlet is applied to the label outlet. So if I type in Hello StackOverflow in the flipside, and then flip it I will see Hello StackOverflow in the main scene.

We did this by going to the method that controls the flip and is in the main scene .m class and added this code.

```
self.label.text = controller.labelText.text;
```

Can anyone explain this code please? I understand that label and labelText are my names. And text is looking for the text. But I have no idea where self and controller came from and it is not explained in the book. Thank you.

EDIT

Here is the full code with the function that has controller in the function heading. I don't get what is going on in this method. Any explanation would be great.

```
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(HWFlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.flipsidePopoverController = nil;
    }

    self.label.text = controller.labelText.text;    
}
```

Comment: We'll probably need more context than a single line of code to answer where `controller` comes from - it could be defined in the .h file, could be defined in the method containing that line of code. `self` is exactly the same as `this` in Java - it refers to the object running the current method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**self is** the java **this** pointer and therefore points to your object

**text is a property** and would be **getText()**

so self.label.text is this.getLabel().getText() BUT
as it sets **text=something it is setText!**

=> java-bean style getter and setter

**controller** is likely a local variable.. PASSED to the method as an argument
OR it is a member variable on the object of the this instance

---

so it'd be

```
this.getLabel().setText(controller.getLabelText().getText());
```

this = the object you're in and that the main view I think

controller is the flipview

the 'overwrite' is setting the String of our label to the Controller's textfield string

Comment: `this.getController()` is not necessarily accurate. `controller` may be defined elsewhere.

Comment: @MichaelMior sorry you're right.... I assumed here .. and I very likely assumed wrong. ill edit my code

Comment: Added the full function. If you could take a look I'd really appreciate it. I don't understand what is happening with it.

Comment: @gmustudent`flipsideViewControllerDidFinish` is a delegate method (at least appears to be based on the common naming convention of including `Did`). This means that the view controller at some point probably created an `HWFlipsideViewController` and then set its `delegate` to itself.

Comment: But how is writing controller at the end of the function legal? Coming from java that looks ridiculous. And what is writing controller there doing? Because I see we call it in the function. So are you calling that variable?

Comment: think of it as a..... java ActionHandler! It gets set when the main view presents the flipview and gets CALLED by the flipview, when it is done!

Comment: @gmustudent Yes. that is the syntax of objC methods :)

Answer (score 0):

You described, that you are in the context, where the flip is controlled. So the instance of the second controller (named `controller`) must be available there. So you may refer to it.

`self` is, as Xono stated in the comment already the pointer to the current object like `this` in java.